# Can one use VBA to create a new chart type in PowerPoint?

Tags: vba, charts, powerpoint

I don't believe this is possible, but I would love to have confirmation from PowerPoint VBA experts.

I am trying to make a chart in PowerPoint that is essentially a bar graph whose bars have a variable width (i.e. the width of each bar is an input into the chart, as opposed to your classic bar chart, which has a set width for each bar).  This is of course not possible in PowerPoint as there is no such chart type for this.

Is it possible to use VBA code to create something like this?  I have a hunch that it is not and that I am limited to interacting with the PowerPoint library and the set chart types.

Any insight into this will be greatly appreciated.  I am struggling to think of a solution for displaying my data in this particular manner.

Comment: is the width a function of the chartdata, or is it just an input? Will each bar be the same width (specified either by input or by function of the chartdata) or is each bar's width need to be defined indpendently of the others?

Comment: The width is just an input.  Each bar's width is independently defined.  These are good clarifications.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the chart in this tutorial: [Variable Width Column Charts (Cascade Charts)](http://peltiertech.com/variable-width-column-charts/)? It's probably easier to do in Excel, because the data isn't a layer further removed from the chart, but you could follow the same protocol in PowerPoint. This is a manual protocol; I've written VBA to do it in Excel, and I'm *going to* do the same for PowerPoint when I get a chance.